# jQuery separating string of phrase values

Tags: jquery

So, I have the following js:

```
function(data){
    var length  = (data.number.split(',').length) - 1; //Holds numbers such as "1,2,3,4,5" which gives "5".         
    var content = data.content; //Holds the phrases
    alert(content); 
        for (var i=0; i<length; i++) {
                var indi_cont = data.content[i];                    
                alert(indi_cont);                   
            };                      
        };
```

Here, the `length` is 5 and I get 5 array of values for the `alert(content)` (note the `" , "` at the end of values).

```
`my name is,how are you,i am good,thank you,hey you,`
```

Using the `for` function, I want to separate each value as below:

```
my name is
how are you
i am good
thank you
hey you
```

However, i am getting `alert(indi_cont)` as following:

```
m
y
n
a
m
```

So, it looks like individual characters are shown instead of the whole phrase.

How do fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Which variable hold the value `my name is,how are you,i am good,thank you,hey you,`?

Comment: `data.content` holds the phrase. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should store the returned string from split like following :

```
function(data){
   //var length  = (data.number.split(',').length) - 1; //gives "5" 
   var splitStr = data.content.split(',');         
   //var content = data.content; 
   //alert(content); 
   for (var i=0; i< (splitStr.length - 1 ); i++) {
       var indi_cont = splitStr[i];                    
       alert(indi_cont);                   
   }                     
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/norlihazmeyGhazali/17Lu8qvc/)

Comment: no, the `data.number` simply holds how many values are there. (It holds something like `"1,3,2,5,4"`. `data.content` holds the phrases

Comment: Then you should split the content itself, see updated answer

Comment: Thank you. Should have realized to split the content as well. Thank you. Got it working! =)

Comment: Just a quick question. Because a phrase can often contain `","` as a part of the sentence, this might screw up splits functions. I was thinking maybe I will add unusual symbols like `",*&^"` instead of  `","` so there is an unique distinction between phrases. What do you think?

Comment: Then you need to look more about split function using regular expression to match if you have more than one symbols like to split with any kind of separation. Like his `guest271314` answer. As example `data.split(/,|&/)`

Comment: I use the symbol `|` for splitting, it is quite uncommon on a regular text and works well.

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the return value of the split function in array, not the length of it.

Try:

```
function(data){
    var dataArray = data.split(',');
    for (var i=0; i<dataArray.length; i++) {
        var indi_cont = dataArray[i];                    
        console.log(indi_cont);                   
    };                      
};
```

fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/bz9h95ox/

Answer (score 1):

Try using `RegExp` `/,|\s/` at `.split()` to split input text at comma character `","` and `" "` space character, `Array.prototype.filter()` with parameter `Boolean` to remove empty `" "` from results of `.split()`

```js
var data = "my name is,how are you,i am good,thank you,hey you,";

var content = data.split(/,|\s/).filter(Boolean);

console.log(content)

for (var i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
  document.body.innerHTML += content[i] + "<br>"
}
```

```html
<body>
  
</body>
```

Alternatively, using `.match()` with `RegExp` `/[a-z0-9]+[^,\s]/ig` to match alphanumeric characters negating comma characters `","` or space `" "` characters

```js
var data = "my name is,how are you,i am good,thank you,hey you,";

var content = data.match(/[a-z0-9]+[^,\s]/ig);

console.log(content)

for (var i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
  document.body.innerHTML += content[i] + "<br>"
}
```

```html
<body>
  
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how i would do it:

```
function(data){
    var values = data.content.split(',');
    $.each(values, function (i, value) {
        if (value.length > 0)
            console.log(value);
    });                   
};
```